# Условие, чтобы 4 числа были одновременно не равны

Tags: java, случайные-числа

Привет. У меня последовательно генерируются 4 числа рандомно в интервале от 1 до 8.
Но иногда, разумеется, генерация совпадает и некоторые из 4 чисел могут оказаться равны. Как можно сделать, чтобы сгенерировались точно все разные? 
Сначала хотел использовать цикл while, но не знаю как составить условие на одновременное равенство 4 чисел. Да к тому же программа будет долго выполняться.

Comment: А сгенерить одно, а потом из него получить (скажем, прибавляя 1) остальные 3 это из какх-то соображений нехорощо?

Comment: они будут не совсем "рандомными".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Кладём все сгенерированные числа в `Set` и смотрим на его размер. Если после добавления 4 чисел в `Set`'е меньше 4 элементов, значит, некоторые числа совпали и нужно сгенерировать новые. Вот пример кода (код демонстрирует идею, за работоспособность не ручаюсь):

```
Set<Integer> numbers = new HashSet<Integer>();
Random r = new Random();
while (numbers.size() < 4) {
    numbers.add(r.nextInt());
}
```

Comment: Думаю, **что для 4-х чисел** это более накладно, чем каждый раз пробегать  по массиву максимум из 3-х элементов.

Answer (score 7):

Заранее составить все возможные варианты последовательностей чисел (их всего-то 8 * 7 * 6 * 5 = 1680), генерировать случайное число от 0 до 1679. Максимально производительный вариант.

Comment: Производительней некуда

Comment: @Veikedo, precalc + O(1). Можете быстрее?

Comment: Даже предварительные вычисления не нужны, можно составить программу, которая сразу сгенерит соответствующий код. Я так постоянно делаю.

Comment: А если числа от 1 до 1000000?

Comment: Вы осознаёте, что меняете условие задачи по ходу задачи? С тем же успехом я могу спросить, сколько будет два плюс три, а услышав Ваш ответ "пять", сказать: "А ведь если заменить сложение на умножение, Ваш ответ уже не будет правильным!" И как бы Вы назвали человека, который предъявляет такие возражения к Вашему решению "2 + 3 = 5"?

Comment: Эеее, нет. Не совсем так. 

Здесь (после комментария "precalc + O(1)") очевидно же, что пошло уже обсуждение не конкретной задачи, а подходов к решению ряда похожих задач.

Comment: > И как бы Вы назвали человека, который предъявляет такие возражения к Вашему решению "2 + 3 = 5"?

я бы назвал его "заказчик". Это вполне обыденная ситуация, когда при разработке ПО требования к продукту меняются, в том числе и после того, как были выполнены предыдущие требования. По-хорошему программа должна разрабатываться так, чтобы программист был максимально готов к возможным изменениям. Напротив, программиста, который жестко завязывается на те или иные условия, сложно назватьквалифицированным. А все последующие разговоры относительно "но раньше же было по-другому" - это в пользу бедных

Comment: +1. комбинаторно идеальный вариант.  
@DreamChild, в пользу бедных это ascii vs unicode, x86 vs x64, вместо тринадцати карт в масти миллион, не шестигранный кубик и не два и не пять, а сто стогранных... оверинжениринг это.

Comment: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAGNI

Если ко мне придёт заказчик и скажет, что ему вместо 8 надо 1000000, то я, во-первых, сделаю себе пометку никогда с ним больше не иметь дела, а во-вторых, переделаю код. Для такого большого числа коллизии крайне маловероятны, поэтому можно сделать две функции: одна заполняет массив случайными значениями, а другая проверяет, все ли они уникальны. Перезаполнение будет происходить крайне редко.

Оба решения хороши для своих случаев, но крайне плохи "в вакууме".

Однако во многих случая быстрее и проще переписать, чем придумывать универсальный сферический метод

Comment: @VadimTukaev, с [KISS](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF_KISS) Вы тоже, наверняка, знакомы.

Comment: >Если ко мне придёт заказчик и скажет, что ему вместо 8 надо 1000000,

а я и не говорю про 1000000. Чтобы производительность таким макаром окончательно издохла, достаточно куда меньших величин. Факториал растет очень быстро, и уже при увеличении исходного значения с 8  10 вы получите 151 200 вариантов, при увеличении до 12 имеем 19 958 400 возможных перестановок, если же увеличить исходное значение до 16, то результат будет и вовсе плачевным - 871 782 912 000. И если вариант с 1000000 выглядит неправдоподобно, то изменение исходного значения с 8 до 16 к области фантастики уж точно не отнесешь

Comment: Тогда всё будет зависеть от количества требуемых чисел. Если их 4, и точно известно, что количество не изменится (например, это времена года), то мне нравится такой вариант:

    int a, b, c, d;
    a = rand();
    do { b = rand(); } while( b == a );
    do { c = rand(); } while( c == a || c == b );
    do { d = rand(); } while( d == a || d == b || d == c );

Один из случаев, когда китайский код вполне оправдан и даже красив.

Comment: Мне очень нравится Ваш вариант, то, что хотелось.

Answer (score 6):

Как то так:

```
int[] numbers = new int[4];
int number, j, i=0;
Random r=new Random();
while(i < 4) {
    number=r.nextInt();
    for(j=0; j < i; j++) {
      if(numbers[j]==number)
         break;
    }
    if(j == i)
      numbers[i++]=number;
}
```

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, то `if(j == i)`

Comment: Да, верно :) - поменял

Answer (score 2):

Немного c# никому не помешает

```
var rand = new Random();
var list = new List<int>();

while(list.Count < 4)
{
    int r = rand.Next();

    if(list.All(x => x != r))
    {
        list.Add(r);
    }
}
```